# How to add AD Administrator to Azure SQL Managed Instance with Powershell

Tags: sql, azure, powershell, cloud, azure-sql-database

I need to add AD administrator to Azure SQL Managed Instances through PowerShell in order to automate deployments.

But it seems there's no way to do it with Azure PowerShell or the REST APIs.
So far I've been trying to set it up like a normal SQL Server.

```
$sql = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "RSGName" -Name "InstanceName" 
-ResourceType "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances" -ExpandProperties

$dbaId = Get-AzureRmADGroup -DisplayName "ADGroupName" | Select-Object Id

Set-AzureRmSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -DisplayName "ADGroupName" 
-ResourceGroupName "RSGName" -ServerName "InstanceName" -ObjectId $dbaId.Id
```

But it is giving me errors saying the Server cannot be found on the resource group.

Comment: That's the script but you must have some data wrong. Check the server name, resource group or the display name.

Comment: The script is correct, I have double checked that many times. I think it is because with Managed Instances you do not manage a server like traditional SQL servers, and the latter is what Set-AzureRmSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator expects.

Comment: Have you tried from the portal https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure#provision-an-azure-active-directory-administrator-for-your-managed-instance

Comment: check whether do you have really have that resource group `Get-AzureRmResourceGroup`

Comment: If it says it can't find it in the resource group, then the next troubleshooting step is to list the contents of the RG and see what powershell sees. https://vincentlauzon.com/2016/01/21/listing-resources-under-resource-group-with-azure-powershell/